# Force Rails 3 encoding to iso-8859-1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8

I am upgrading a rails 2 app to rails 3 and have a huge database encoded in latin 1. Lots of characters now appear messed up and the reason seems to be that rails is converting the text to UTF-8. I've tried converting the mysql db, which isn't going to work. Now I'm trying to force rails to use iso-8859-1 throughout the application.

I've updated my mysql config with:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: latin1
...
```

and application.rb with:

```
config.encoding = "ISO-8859-1"
config.action_controller.default_charset = 'ISO-8859-1'
config.action_dispatch.default_charset = 'ISO-8859-1'
```

When I try to navigate to my app I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1):
```

How do I get rails to stop trying to use UTF-8?